# Could not find activemodel-3.2.0 in any of the sources (Rails 3.2 on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

I'm very new to Rails and Heroku, but have a very simple app running locally.

I thought I'd try to get in running on Heroku, but alas I keep running into the same problem.

```
Could not find activemodel-3.2.0 in any of the sources
```

There are related questions here on Stack Overflow, but none of their suggestions or answers seem to resolve this issue for me.

Other posts attempting to answer this ask for the Gemfile, so here's mine

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Here's my Gemfile.lock

```
GEM


remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.0)
      actionpack (= 3.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.0)
      activemodel (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.0)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.0)
      activemodel (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      arel (~> 3.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.0)
      activemodel (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
    activesupport (3.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.1)
    jquery-rails (2.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.5)
    mail (2.4.1)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    pg (0.12.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.0)
      actionpack (= 3.2.0)
      activerecord (= 3.2.0)
      activeresource (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.0)
    railties (3.2.0)
      actionpack (= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (= 3.2.0)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.2.4)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Here's more of the heroku logs

```
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/specifications/activeresource-3.2.0.gemspec'
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     s.add_dependency(%q<activemodel>, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000000089d28c8> 3.2.0"])
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   end
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]: end
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     s.add_dependency(%q<activesupport>, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000000089d3d40> 3.2.0"])
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   else
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]:       s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<activemodel>, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x000000089d28c8> 3.2.0"])
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not find activemodel-3.2.0 in any of the sources
2012-02-03T23:28:53+00:00 app[web.1]: !! Unexpected error while processing request: exit
```

Result of `heroku info --app <my app>`

```
=== <my app>
Addons:        Basic Logging, Shared Database 5MB
Database Size: (empty)
Dynos:         1
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:<my app>.git
Owner:         me@myemail.com
Repo Size:     7M
Slug Size:     6M
Stack:         bamboo-mri-1.9.2
Web URL:       http://<my app>.heroku.com/
Workers:       0
```

If anyone has any good ideas, that'd be great. And if you could explain them on super-newbie terms, that'd be even better. Thanks.

Comment: Please also paste: your `Gemfile.lock`, the result of running `git status` (it should be clean), the result when you try to push, and the output of `heroku logs --app <your app>`.

Comment: Also, what do you get for `heroku info --app <your app>`?

Comment: Hey John, thanks for responding. I've added my Gemfile.lock above and more of the heroku logs. `git status` returns `# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)' and `git push heroku master` returns `Everything up-to-date`.

Comment: Also added result of `heroku info --app <your app>` above. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running the project on a Bamboo stack. Heroku suggests that you run Rails 3.2 applications on the Cedar stack, because Rails 3.2 requires certain more modern versions of Rubygems and Ruby to function properly.

You can downgrade and use the Rails 3.0.x series instead, if you need to be on Bamboo for some reason.

Otherwise, you can create a new Cedar app with:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

and push your code as you would before, after you update your `heroku` remote.

Comment: Thanks for your help John. This worked a treat. If anybody else is new to all this, like me, you can update your heroku remote by manually editing the file `.git/config`, although there's probably a way of doing it in Terminal.

Comment: You can update the heroku remote with `git remote rm heroku`, then `git remote add heroku ...`.

Comment: Directions for migrating an existing app to the cedar stack: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration